# Call webservices in android on textchanged listener on one edit text and populate another edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am able to call webservices now.

But In my project i want to populate the name of sponser corresponding to the sponser id .

For doing this I want to call a webservice on text changed listener of sponserid edittext or i have to monitor the focus changed of edittext.

Please guide me how to call webservice and populate another edittext.

Should i take keyevent ???

The codes i have tried so far are :

```
txtSpnID.setFocusable(true);
        if(txtSpnID.isFocused()){
            Log.v("TAG", "focus is on txtspid");
        }else{
            Log.v("TAG", "focus lost from txtspid");
        }
```

This prints focus lost from txtspid on logcat.

```
if(txtSpnID.hasFocus()){
            Log.v("TAG", "focus is on txtspid");
        }else{
            Log.v("TAG", "focus lost from txtspid");
        }
```

this also prints the same

```
txtSpnID.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.v("textfield","On text changed");
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                    int arg2, int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.v("textfield","before text changed");
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.v("textfield text",txtSpnID.getText().toString());
                Toast.makeText(Registration.this, "SponserID is"+txtSpnID.getText().toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                if (txtSpnID.getText().length() == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(Registration.this, "Enter SponserID ",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                } else {
                    String spnId = txtSpnID.getText().toString();
                    try {
            //call webservice here and get response from the service
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

this prints corresponding logs on logcat
but it does not show toast :(
please help me guys

Comment: Toast.makeText(...).**show()**;

Comment: .... remeber to call web service in different thread(to prevent ANR)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just made Toast ... but you did'nt show it ... use [Toast.show()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#show%28%29) like this `Toast.makeToast(.....).show();`

.... remeber to call web service in different thread(to prevent ANR)

Comment: yes it was silly thing i missed in toast but tell me now should i make a function to call webservices and call that function here ??